# Rows and colums with bootstrap not working

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid, bootstrap-cards

So im trying to display multiple cards in a row I followed the documentation but for some reason my cards keep displaying in a single colum. Can anyone see what im doing wrong??

```
<section class="feature p-5">
  <h2 class="text-center">Recomendaciones de la semana</h2>
  <h4 class="text-center">Esta semana nuestras recomendaciones giran alrededor de autores latinoamericanos</h4>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-sm">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="img/books/linro1.webp" alt="foto portada del libro" class="card-img-top">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h3 class="card-title">Pedro Paramo - Juan Rulfo</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="img/books/linro1.webp" alt="foto portada del libro" class="card-img-top">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title">Pedro Paramo - Juan Rulfo</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was you nested a column inside a column.

Wrong:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm">
    <div class="col-sm"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Correct:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm"></div>
  <div class="col-sm"></div>
</div>
```

See the snippet below.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<section class="feature p-5">
  <h2 class="text-center">Recomendaciones de la semana</h2>
  <h4 class="text-center">Esta semana nuestras recomendaciones giran alrededor de autores latinoamericanos</h4>
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-sm">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="img/books/linro1.webp" alt="foto portada del libro" class="card-img-top">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h3 class="card-title">Pedro Paramo - Juan Rulfo</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="img/books/linro1.webp" alt="foto portada del libro" class="card-img-top">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h3 class="card-title">Pedro Paramo - Juan Rulfo</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```